# How to index composite primary keys in hibernate search

Tags: hibernate-search

I have the following class definitions and for class UserAdAccount, it uses both the adAccountId and userId as its composite primary key. I need to use this composite primary key as the document id for indexing.

After reading the Hibernate Search 5.11.5.Final: Reference Guide(This is the version I am using), I found the following:
The more powerful TwoWayFieldBridge interface allows you to store more than one field into the index, which can be useful for composite properties, but is more complex to implement.

I am not sure how to proceed using the TwoWayFieldBridge to address my need here. Any help is appreciated!

```
@Entity (name = "JHI_USER_AD_ACCOUNT")
@Indexed
@IdClass(UserAdAccountId.class)
@Getter
@Setter
public class UserAdAccount implements SearchableEntity, Serializable { 
    //newly added id field with two way string bridge
    @DocumentId
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @FieldBridge(impl = UserAdAccoutPrimaryKeyBridge.class)
    private UserAdAccountId id;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "AD_ACCOUNT_ID")
    @GenericGenerator( name = "native", strategy = "native")
    @Field
    private Long adAccountId;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "USER_ID")
    @GenericGenerator( name = "native", strategy = "native")
    @Field
    private Long userId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID", updatable = false, insertable = false)
    @JsonIgnore
    private User user;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "AD_ACCOUNT_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID", updatable = false, insertable = false)
    @IndexedEmbedded(includePaths = "name")
    private AdAccount adAccount;
}


@Getter
@Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = {"userId", "adAccountId"})
public class UserAdAccountId implements Serializable {
    private Long userId;
    private Long adAccountId;
}


public class UserAdAccoutPrimaryKeyBridge implements TwoWayStringBridge {

    @Override
    public String objectToString(Object object) {
        UserAdAccountId userAdAccountId = (UserAdAccountId) object;
        StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
        buffer.append(userAdAccountId.getUserId()).append("-").append(userAdAccountId.getAdAccountId());
        return buffer.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public Object stringToObject(String value) {
        String[] components = value.split("-");
        UserAdAccountId userAdAccountId = new UserAdAccountId();
        userAdAccountId.setUserId(Long.parseLong(components[0]));
        userAdAccountId.setAdAccountId(Long.parseLong(components[1]));
        return userAdAccountId;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.11/reference/en-US/html_single/#section-two-way-bridge):

> It is important for the two-way process to be idempotent, i.e.:
> [...]
>
> - for TwoWayFieldBridge: for a given document, the object returned by get() must be the same as the one that was originally passed to set().
>
> Also, in order for TwoWayFieldBridge implementations to work correctly when used on a document identifier, the void set(String name, Object value, Document document, LuceneOptions luceneOptions) method must add a field to the document following these conventions:
>
> - the field name must be the name provided in the name parameter
> - the field value must be encoded as a String
> - the field value must be unique to the given value of the value parameter
> - the field value must match what the objectToString method would return for the given value parameter.

You can find an example implementation for a composite primary key [on github](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-search/blob/f62a71ed9c3e9daad6dc28f2e2967955b8889c2d/legacy/orm/src/test/java/org/hibernate/search/test/id/PersonPKBridge.java#L22-L21):

```java
public class PersonPKBridge implements TwoWayFieldBridge, MetadataProvidingFieldBridge {

    private static final String FIRST_NAME_SUFFIX = "_content.firstName";
    private static final String LAST_NAME_SUFFIX = "_content.lastName";

    @Override
    public void configureFieldMetadata(String name, FieldMetadataBuilder builder) {
        builder.field( name + FIRST_NAME_SUFFIX, FieldType.STRING )
            .field( name + LAST_NAME_SUFFIX, FieldType.STRING );
    }

    @Override
    public Object get(String name, Document document) {
        PersonPK id = new PersonPK();
        IndexableField field = document.getField( name + FIRST_NAME_SUFFIX );
        id.setFirstName( field.stringValue() );
        field = document.getField( name + LAST_NAME_SUFFIX );
        id.setLastName( field.stringValue() );
        return id;
    }

    @Override
    public String objectToString(Object object) {
        PersonPK id = (PersonPK) object;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append( id.getFirstName() ).append( " " ).append( id.getLastName() );
        return sb.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public void set(String name, Object value, Document document, LuceneOptions luceneOptions) {
        PersonPK id = (PersonPK) value;

        //store each property in a unique field
        luceneOptions.addFieldToDocument( name + FIRST_NAME_SUFFIX, id.getFirstName(), document );

        luceneOptions.addFieldToDocument( name + LAST_NAME_SUFFIX, id.getLastName(), document );

        //store the unique string representation in the named field
        luceneOptions.addFieldToDocument( name, objectToString( id ), document );
    }

}
```

Alternatively, if you're certain the components of your ID don't contain a certain string, you will be able to use that string as a separator for the indexed form of your ID, and you'll be able to convert that indexed form back to the original ID. This means you can use the simpler `TwoWayStringBridge` and rely on concatenation/splitting:

```java
public class PersonPKBridge implements TwoWayStringBridge {

    @Override
    public String objectToString(Object object) {
        PersonPK id = (PersonPK) object;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append( id.getFirstName() ).append( " " ).append( id.getLastName() );
        return sb.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public Object stringToObject(String value) {
        String[] components = value.split(" ");
        PersonPK id = new PersonPK();
        id.setFirstName( components[0] );
        id.setLastName( components[1] );
        return id;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Both the ad account and user ids in my case are digits only, so I can use the simpler TwoWayStringBridge. After implementing it, I then add a new field  in my class, right?(see the updated class)

Comment: @Lyn Yes you should use `@FieldBridge` to apply the bridge.

Comment: This new id field does not need to be saved in DB, right? i.e, I do not need to use the @Column annotation.

Comment: I tried both options but ran into the same error: in the objectToString(Object object) method, I got a null object passed as a parameter, did I miss anything? or should I add a null check to skip null objects?

Comment: I've updated my class and added a two way string bridge class, but still keep getting null object error. My understanding is that since I used the @IdClass(UserAdAccountId.class) annotation, I need to add a new field of type UserAdAccountId. This field contains userId and adAccountId, which can be used in the two way string bridge. Please correct me if I am wrong on this. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I just noticed you were using `@IdClass`... Unfortunately entities with `@IdClass` aren't supported yet (https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HSEARCH-1715); the only workaround would be to use `@EmbeddedId` instead (https://discourse.hibernate.org/t/nullpointerexception-when-using-latest-hibernate-search-6-with-idclass/3937/2?u=yrodiere).

Comment: I see. I updated my implementation to use embedded id. But when I do a hibernate search, I am getting the unable to find field path error. To avoid confusion with this original question, I created a new post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63237934/hibernate-search-on-embedded-composite-primary-key.   Can you help me identify the incorrectness in my new implementation? Many thanks!